# Which file system should I use for Micro SD card, APFS encrypted or HFS+ encrypted?

Tags: filesystem, sd-card

I have a 256GB Micro SD Card (TF Card). I plan to use it as an external storage to my Macbook. I don't care about the portability. So no need to use exFAT file system. To be safe, I plan to use encryption fs. So it ends up two choices: APFS (encrypted) or Mac OS Extended (Journaled,Encrypted).

Which one is has better performance characteristics for SD cards?

Comment: Go with JHFS+ because APFS was designed for SSDs and any performance gain you would have gotten from APFS is complexly negated by ridiculously slow speed of a mSD card.

Comment: @Allan thanks a lot for the suggestion. I have upvoted your comment. Btw, one more quesiton, does case-sensitive or case-insensitive matter for microSD card? If not matter, I prefer case sensitive choice. BUT my internal ssd storage is case-insensitive recommended by many people. (PS: my microSD card is Sandisk Extreme 256G)

Comment: Everything else is case sensitive to stick with that.  From the SD card perspective, it doesn't care, but you'll run into some unpredictable results with a case insensitive file system like copying a file from your internal drive to your external and back again.

Comment: Wait...people *recommended* your internal drive be *case insensitive*???

Comment: @Allan I read some articles and asked some questions on different forums in the past. People said some softwares in MacOS don't work on case sensitive filesystem. That's why I format my internal storage as case-insensitive filesystem even if I don't like it at all because I come from Linux world. For instance, this is [one article I just googled](https://itnerd.blog/2017/11/17/should-you-format-your-mac-hard-drive-to-be-case-sensitive-or-not-case-sensitive/).

Comment: If ADFS has no advantage, then, why the Sandisk has this article? https://kb-in.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20542/~/converting-external-drive-to-apple-file-system-%28apfs%29-format